# Show that z is a real number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, real-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number such that $z$,$z$<sup>$2$</sup>,$z$<sup>$3$</sup> are collinear in the complex plane. Show that $z$ is a real number.

Comment: Hint: let $z$ = $Re^{i\theta}$. What does collinear tell us about $\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z$, $z^2$, and $z^3$ are collinear, then
$$z^3 - z^2 = r(z^2 - z)$$
for some real number $r$. Then divide both sides by $(z^2 - z)$ (assuming $z \neq 0$) to get $z = r$.

Answer (score 1):

let $z=\exp(i\theta)$ then $z^2=\exp(i2\theta)$,...,$z^n=\exp(in\theta)$.

If $z,z^2,\cdots$ is collinear, then $Arg(z)=\pm Arg(z^2)=\cdots$. Since $Arg(2\pi)=Arg(0)$, this implies $\theta=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: This assumes that the line goes through 0. Had the same issue in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Case (1).$z=0$ or $z=1$.Trivial. Case (2). $0\ne z\ne 1$. There exists $A\in R$ such that $z^2=A z+(1-A)z^3$. Dividing by $z$ gives $z=A+(1-A)z^2$. The solutions for $z$ in this quadratic equation  are real because $A\in R$ and the discriminant is $1-4(1-A)A=(1-2A)^2$ which is a non-negative real.